# After messing with my grub settings, I can't log into debian

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub

So I was unwisely screwing around with the grub settings. I made modifications but forgot to update-grub before I rebooted. not sure if I accidentally made other modifications. Now, I can't log into Debian... it gets to the log-in screen and accepts my (correct) non-root username and password, but then it flashes a black screen and then just goes back to the login screen. same story with root & its password.

I can still boot the thing into recovery mode, (although it failed to boot at all at least once when I re-modified the GRUB settings, which is making me a bit gun-shy about re-modifying it). I can still view the grub command line settings when selecting the 'e' option in the grub boot menu... here they are (hand-transcribed... sorry if I make errors).

```
setparams 'Debian GNU/Linux'

   load_video
   insmod gzip
   if [x$grub_platform = xxen ] ; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
   insmod part_msdos
   insmod ext2
   if [x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ];then 
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  df2b4936-8f0c-yadda-yadda
   else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root df2b4936-8f0c-yadda-yadda
   fi
   echo 'Loading Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 ...'
   linux /boot/vmlinux-4.9.0-8-amd64 root=UUID df2b4936-8f0c-yadda-yadda ro conssole=ttyS1 conssole=ttyS1 quiet maxcpus=1
   echo 'loading initial ramdisk ...'
   initrd /boot/init.rd.img-4.9.0-8-amd64
```

...I note that the first 'search' function has a double space, like it was trying to insert an unset environment variable in there... but its not related to what I was messing with. what I was messing with was the linux command line parameters (which is why console= is in there twice). I've tried several variations on those parameters and seen no difference... Anybody see anything else wrong?

Edit: now I can't boot into recovery mode either, and recovery mode has its own non-screwed-up GRUB settings... I think this is unrelated to my unwise modifications.